# Bulleted multi-line labels with text on left and right hand sides

Tags: formatting, lists, bullets

I would like to replicate the format as shown below in the image (specifically the bullets with multi-line labels with text on either side).
[image]

Following is the command I'm using:

```
\subsection{First line left text \hfill First line right text\\\ second line left text\hfill second line right text\\}
```

However this isn't working for me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Probably you are liiking for `itemize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to show than explain.  Your picture showed the first bullet centered on the text rather that at the top, hence the `\parbox`.  There are other characters than `$\circ$` one can use as bullets.  See [CTAN symbols](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en) and [CTAN fontawsome](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome?lang=en)

The enumitem package makes changing the margins and bullet slightly easier.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only
\leftmargini=1em
\leftmarginii=2.5em
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{itemize}
\item\parbox{\linewidth}{First line left text \hfill First line right text\par
  %\leftskip=0.5em \righjtskip=0.5em % apply to all following lines
  %second line left text\hfill second line right text}
  \hspace*{0.5em}second line left text\hfill second line right text\hspace*{0.5em}}% one line only
\begin{itemize}\rightskip=\bibindent
  \item[$\circ$] next level.
  \item[$\circ$] \blindtext
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]