# Keep text in different lines to the right of bullets

Tags: formatting, align, vertical-alignment

As the title say, I want to keep a block of text neatly to the right of a bullet (or a circle).

For example, here’s some of my code:

```
\noindent $\bullet$ We will explore the following properties of $ASM_n$:

$\circ$ The number of facets.

$\circ$ Its vertices.

$\circ$ Projection to the permutohedron (no proof).

\noindent $\bullet$ Tool: flow grids

$\circ$ Consider a $(n+2) \times (n+2)$ grid with $2$-dimensional Cartesian coordinates (with $(0,0)$ shifted to top left).

$\circ$ Take the $4n$ "boundary vertices" and $n^2$ internal vertices.

$\circ$ Define the $\emph{complete flow grid } C_n$ as the directed graph on these vertices, with edge set:
$$\{ ((i,j),(i,j \pm 1)),((i,j),(i \pm 1,j)) \ | \ i,j \in [n] \}$$
```

which gives me:

[image]

How do I keep that “(with (0,0)…)” to the right of the circle on the previous line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulleted multi-line labels with text on left and right hand sides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519614/bulleted-multi-line-labels-with-text-on-left-and-right-hand-sides)

Comment: I prefer not to use \begin{align} \end{align} if possible. I’m using a tool that doesn’t handle environments very well.

Answer (score 5):

`enumitem` is a good tool for this.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\blabla{Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla,
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
    \item \blabla{}
    
    \begin{itemize}[label=$\circ$]
        \item \blabla{}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This produces :

[image]